# How do you update one variable in a load-save table in corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Is it possible to update one variable of a table using the load/save json saving method?I want to change one value/variable in another .lua file. How do I accomplish this?

My main.lua:

```
local table = {}
 table.one = "no"
 table.two = "no"
 table.three = "no"

loadsave.saveTabe(table, "trying.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)
```

in check.lua:

```
local value = loadsave.loadTable("trying.json, system.DocumentsDirectory)

   if( 5+5 == 10)then
      value.one = "yes"
     --HERE I WANT TO SAVE THE VALUE TO THE SAME JSON FILE WITHOUT CHANGING THE OTHER VALUES/VARIABLES ETC.
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
local value = loadsave.loadTable("trying.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)

if( 5+5 == 10) then
    value.one = "yes"
    loadsave.saveTable(value, "trying.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)
end
```

Comment: wow, I have no idea why I didn't think of this simple answer :D